# What backed databases is best to use with a react native app?

Tags: web-apps, database, web-development, web-server, react

For my final year project, I will be developing website and database for a property management company case study.I have chosen react native to develop the front-end. What back-end technologies will be suitable to integrate with such a react native app?

Comment: They're pretty much separate in a typical client-server architecture. First choose your backend stack, then choose a DB accordingly. Also, and most important for this site, be sure to document all the features you may need for this database server.

Comment: As Alejandro says, your front-end is completely separate from the back-end, so you can choose any backend technology. You can interface with the backend using Axios. Some common backend frameworks are: node.js (specifically express.js or sails.js), or .net core. Various database that you can integrate with are: MongoDB, MySql, MSSQL.